# play.data.Form<> not filling j.u.Map<> fields when deserializing request body into object

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.1

I really like Form in playframework but I have noticed something strange when I have a class that has a field which is a `Map<>`

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonSetter;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonDeserialize;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GameState {

    private String roomId = "";

    private String woohoo = "";

    @JsonDeserialize(as = LinkedHashMap.class, contentAs = Integer.class, keyAs = String.class)
    private Map<String, Integer> players = new HashMap<String, Integer>();


    @JsonProperty("players")
    public Map<String, Integer> getPlayers() {
        return players;
    }

    @JsonSetter("players")
    public GameState setPlayers(Map<String, Integer> players) {
        this.players = players;
        return this;
    }

    public String getRoomId() {
        return roomId;
    }

    public GameState setRoomId(String roomId) {
        this.roomId = roomId;
        return this;
    }

    public String getWoohoo() {
        return woohoo;
    }

    public GameState setWoohoo(String woohoo) {
        this.woohoo = woohoo;
        return this;
    }
}
```

In my controller I have the following static form:

```
static Form<GameState> gameForm = new Form<GameState>(GameState.class);
```

and then I have the following action:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
public static Result testAction() {
    Form<GameState> form = gameForm.bindFromRequest();
    if (!form.hasErrors()) {
        GameState s = form.get();
        if (!s.getPlayers().isEmpty()) {
            return ok();
        } else {
            return badRequest("Need players!");
        }
    } else {
        return badRequest("Wrong format!");
    }
}
```

This de-serialize any other field (`List<>` and `Set<>` included when I had classes with such fields) but **NOT** `Map<>` fields. The strange thing is that it works for:

```
GameState s = Json.fromJson(request().body().asJson(), GameState.class);
```

Here is a curl call I use to test the action

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9000/game/end/1 --data '{"roomId": "someid", "woohoo": "something", "players" : { "oliver" : "0" } }' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

I am using Play 2.1. It also does not seem to matter if I have a @BodyParser.Of() or not on that action.

**Question** : Is there a way to make the `form.get()` work properly?